# What is the difference between /usr/bin/python3 and /bin/python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-21.04

So, I was using visual studio code and wanted to see what option do I have for interpreter in vscode in my Ubuntu 21.04 machine and what I found are these [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7I9N.png). First is the virtual environment python interpreter and I guess 2nd is the system python interpreter so what is the 3rd interpreter option that I am getting and this is my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Linux file-hierarchy manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/file-hierarchy.7.html):

> /bin/, /sbin/, /usr/sbin/
>
> These compatibility symlinks point to /usr/bin/, ensuring that scripts and binaries referencing these legacy paths correctly find their binaries.

In my computer (Ubuntu 20.04) `/bin/python3` is a link to `/usr/bin/python3.8`. Basically, the link `/bin/python3` exists so that legacy programs that look for the python executable in `/bin` work.

Answer (score 2):

Both `/usr/bin/python3` and `/bin/python3` are symbolic links to the same Python interpreter. So the only difference between them is path.